# Use javascript to simulate a click on HTML select option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I am trying to use checkboxes to select an option in an HTML select element. I have it NEARLY working and a working demo can be seen here - https://ecommerce-ds-addons.webflow.io/product/bag-addons-as-variants - if you tick the checkboxes marked "Cycling Clips" or "Red Safety Light" - you can see that the faded out select boxs above change.

However, the price should change and when the item is added to cart, these "Add-ons" should be included - but they are not. If you select the dropdowns manually using your mouse, you will see how it should work.

A simplified version of the javascript I am using is:

```
$("select :nth-child(2)").prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

Is there a way to simulate a click that will work in this instance?

I found this piece of code on another thread and it worked when a jquery trigger or click would not work. However, I 've tried this and it didn't work either.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        // 'this' is not a jQuery object, so it will use
        // the default click() function
        this.click();
    }).click();
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for if you checked checkbox than select box option is selected.

For example:
HTML:

```
<div>
<select id="newselect" name="newselect">
  <option value="newoptionone">New Option One</option>
  <option value="newoptiontwo">New Option Two</option>
  <option value="nothing" selected="selected">Nothing</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<input id="newcheckbox" name="newcheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1"/>New Checkbox
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
          // $("#newselect option:eq(1)").val("nothing");
           $("#newselect").val($("#newselect option:eq(1)").val());
        }
        else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
            $("#newselect").val($("#newselect option:eq(2)").val());
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I've tried your code but it still does not register with the cart as a change for some reason.

See here your code working on the cycling clip box (it's a div not a checkbox, but works the same - i'm just tracking a click on that, then triggering the select change) - https://ecommerce-ds-addons.webflow.io/product/bag-addons-as-variants

Answer (score 0):

In the events attached to your select, there is something like this

```
function() {
  $(this)...
}
```

maybe the problem is a scope problem, try with something like :

```
function(e) {
  $(e)...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this from your page, pardon the odd selectors but that is outside the question.  So get the text before the " (" then use that to select the proper option and trigger the change.  Note only the "Cycle Clips" is a valid value in this example from the page due to spelling.

This can be much more elegant if we have the option values on the checky thing somewhere like `<div class="checkbox-holder" data-option-value="d846e2515b8c7395944a499dbf6015e3">` then we could do `let thisval = $(this).data("option-value");`.  We could also add a target for the "checky" thing with `data-target="#option-set-02ec6d9777a31120378034ef57c57359"` and use that to find a specific select for this checky thing.  I edited to add the second example that does that on the light.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.w-commerce-commerceaddtocartform')
    .on('click', '.checkbox-holder', function(event) {
      let desc = $(this).find('.checkbox-label').first().text();
      let descValue = desc.substr(0, desc.indexOf(' ('));
      // console.log("'" + descValue + "'");
      // this is the form, we find the selects inside that
      $(event.delegateTarget)
        .find('select.select.w-select')
        .find('option')
        .filter(':contains(' + descValue + ')')
        .each(function() {
          $(this).prop('selected', true)
          // console.log(this);
          $(this).closest('select')
            .trigger('change');
        });
    });
  // data target and value example
  $('.w-commerce-commerceaddtocartform')
    .on('click', '.checkbox-holder', function(event) {
      let selectTarget = $(this).data('target');
      let selctValue = $(this).data("check-value");
      let isChecked = true; // $(this).find('checkbox-field');// something to detect checked or not
      $(selectTarget)
        .find('option[value="' + selctValue + '"]')
        .each(function() {
          $(this).prop('selected', isChecked)
          $(this).closest('select')
            .trigger('change');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.checkbox-holder {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}
```

```html
<form data-node-type="commerce-add-to-cart-form" data-commerce-sku-id="5dd53f32b98acb0ed12d8004" data-loading-text="Adding to cart..." data-commerce-product-id="5dd53f32b98acb49122d7ffd" class="w-commerce-commerceaddtocartform">
  <div role="group" data-wf-sku-bindings="%5B%7B%22from%22%3A%22f_sku_values_3dr%22%2C%22to%22%3A%22optionValues%22%7D%5D" data-commerce-product-sku-values="%7B%2238a7c5187112b57e87fd3e059d184f42%22%3A%224b010dfc26908b131d0de6a7191bf44d%22%2C%2202ec6d9777a31120378034ef57c57359%22%3A%22dd8678fbf5647e7c2149c78f06f3fd12%22%2C%22397f1ba5006bd7c253c4d55ac6a92220%22%3A%22bb2e628cbccceeb10faa80941332650d%22%7D"
    data-node-type="commerce-add-to-cart-option-list" data-commerce-product-id="5dd53f32b98acb49122d7ffd" class="option-list">
    <div role="group" class="option"><label data-wf-bindings="%5B%7B%22innerHTML%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22PlainText%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22identity%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22dataPath%22%3A%22name%22%7D%7D%5D">size</label>
      <select id="option-set-38a7c5187112b57e87fd3e059d184f42" data-node-type="commerce-add-to-cart-option-select" data-commerce-option-set-id="38a7c5187112b57e87fd3e059d184f42" class="select w-select" required="">
        <option selected="" value="">Select size</option>
        <option value="4b010dfc26908b131d0de6a7191bf44d">Medium</option>
        <option value="cdbe5bc68b99681edc0dc58a0c140891">Large</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div role="group" class="option"><label data-wf-bindings="%5B%7B%22innerHTML%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22PlainText%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22identity%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22dataPath%22%3A%22name%22%7D%7D%5D">clips add on</label>
      <select id="option-set-02ec6d9777a31120378034ef57c57359" data-node-type="commerce-add-to-cart-option-select" data-commerce-option-set-id="02ec6d9777a31120378034ef57c57359" class="select w-select" required="">
        <option selected="" value="">Select clips add on</option>
        <option value="06cddab0785e4c8debe8ca6bec42ad74">Cycling Clips</option>
        <option value="dd8678fbf5647e7c2149c78f06f3fd12">Nothing</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div role="group" class="option"><label data-wf-bindings="%5B%7B%22innerHTML%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22PlainText%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22identity%22%2C%22params%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%22dataPath%22%3A%22name%22%7D%7D%5D">lights add on</label>
      <select id="option-set-397f1ba5006bd7c253c4d55ac6a92220" data-node-type="commerce-add-to-cart-option-select" data-commerce-option-set-id="397f1ba5006bd7c253c4d55ac6a92220" class="select w-select" required="">
        <option selected="" value="">Select lights add on</option>
        <option value="d846e2515b8c7395944a499dbf6015e3">Red Cycing Light</option>
        <option value="bb2e628cbccceeb10faa80941332650d">Nothing</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-block">
    <div class="checkbox-holder">
      <div id="clips-checkbox" class="checkbox-field">
        <div class="checkbox" style="border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">
          <div class="checkbox-icon" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-label">Cycling Clips ( + 25 €)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-holder" data-check-value="d846e2515b8c7395944a499dbf6015e3" data-target="#option-set-397f1ba5006bd7c253c4d55ac6a92220">
      <div id="light-checkbox" class="checkbox-field">
        <div class="checkbox" style="border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">
          <div class="checkbox-icon" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-label">Red Safety Light ( + 50 €)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-wf-sku-bindings="%5B%7B%22from%22%3A%22f_price_%22%2C%22to%22%3A%22innerHTML%22%7D%5D" class="product-detail-price">$180.00</div>
  <div class="product-detail-cta-wrap"><input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" class="w-commerce-commerceaddtocartbutton button"></div>
</form>
<script src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.220afd743d.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Mark Schultheiss,

Thank you very much for the comprehensive reply.

I've tried your code but unfortunately it does not work. See here - https://ecommerce-ds-addons.webflow.io/product/bag-addons-as-variants

It works to change "Clips Add On " the selection to "Cycling Clips", however, you will notice that the price does not update. 

If you click the checkbox for the clips, you notice that the price stays at €180 - however, if you change that to "nothing" and then back to "cycling clips" using your mouse, you will see that that price changes. Does that make sense? That's the issue.

Comment: There is a cloneable copy of the actual page here that you can test on - https://webflow.com/website/ecommerce-ds-addons

you will need to create a free account if you want to play with it. here's a quick video explaining it all 
https://www.loom.com/share/99682cf3eb38430c88daa381cd807301

Comment: @diarmuids- frankly my answer does work for your question, your question was how to simulate a click - which this does.  If you have another question - like how to pull the price out of some description (a bad practice) that is another question you can ask. You might also ask a question regarding how to better accomplish what you want, for example use `data-price="50.43"` on the `option` element is better and putting the option value on the "clicky" thing in a data attribute is better which is what I have shown.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes, it does do what I described - however it doesn't work in this instance for some reason (I'm not sure why) so it doesn't solve my problem.It doesn't have to do with pulling out a price - it's to do with simulating a click - just like a user - that updates the price as in the example I posted above. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Using a click to activate a select element selection (the question) is different than the price update - that update should be based upon the change event of the select.  So just put a change event on those select elements should do what you want for that new question.